# Can weights be constrained to binary?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm writing a weighting layer which basically multiplies each input pixel by a weight (Hadamard). I'd like to constrain these weights to be binary (0 or 1). Is there a way to achieve this in Tensorflow (or any other framework)?

I'm aware there was some academic work on this by Bengio et. al. and possibly others, but is there anything that can be done with the current frameworks?

Sincerely,

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to constrain these weights to be binary (0 or 1)

Tensorflow provides [bool datatype](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf#bool) to store binary data. Be careful when using bool data type, because some operations that are allowed for numeric types are not allowed for bool datatype. E.g you can't use `*` `+` `-` etc. with bool datatypes. But you can use operations such as `&`(logical `and`) `|`(logical `or`).

E.g

```
a = tf.Variable([False], dtype=tf.bool)
b = tf.Variable([True], dtype=tf.bool)
c = a | b
d = a & b
f = ~a
```

Comment: My layer multiplies each input pixel with the weight (x * weights). Having the weight set as binary (and using tf.cast to float before the multiplication) results in: "An operation has `None` for gradient. Please make sure that all of your ops have a gradient defined (i.e. are differentiable). Common ops without gradient: K.argmax, K.round, K.eval."